# how to associate the portable subnet to virtual server through API and portal?

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am trying to find the way that we could associate portable subnet to Virtual server by API and portal for the secondary ip address. I read many documents I can't find a good solution for it.

Answer (score 0):

The subnets are associated to VLANs, the only way that you can use the IPs of the subnet is that your Visrtual Server has associated that VLAN, using either API or Portal that only can be done at order moment, in case you want to change the VLAN of the Virtual Server you need to submit a ticket to softlayer and ask them to change the VLAN.

To associate the VLAN to the virtual server at order moment see documentation:

http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/createObject

Regards

Comment: yes, When I order the virtual server, there is option that I could select the VLAN as well as the subnet under VLAN but there is no portable subnet show up during that time. I saw only the primary subnet are listed under the selected subnet while there are also portable subnet in it. I saw on use case is to use as the secondary ip address of the Virtual server. I wonder how can we achieve this

Comment: What the control portal is displaying is fine only primary subnets will be displayed becasue you are picking the subnets for your nics (public or private) and they only can be the primary subnet , but the portable IPs should be available to configure in other resources into your server (e.g. your server will contain virtual servers using VMware). If you are trying to configure the portable IPs for the private and public NICs of your server that is not possible

Comment: Additionaly you can order the porable IPs at order moment using the control portal you just need to pick one of the options from the section "Public Secondary IP Addresses" but the final result should be the same as when you asocciate a VLAN to your VSI

Comment: thanks for the your details answer. so as long as we associate my virtual server to the VLAN that contains the portable subnet, that portable subnet will be available  to configure the resource inside the Virtual server such as VMs, Clusters?

Comment: yep the IPs should be available and you should be able to use them

Comment: according to the document: http://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/learning/utilizing-subnets-and-ips  we could use portable subnet as the  secondary IPs on servers or secondary interfaces. would you mind to explain me more about this point?  Thanks for your time

Comment: you can add to your server secondary IPs here some guides https://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/learning/add-secondary-ips-redhatcentos https://dbiers.me/adding-secondary-ip-addresses-centosrhel/ here some reasons why you would like to do that http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/127723/what-are-the-benefits-of-using-several-ip-addresses-on-a-server all depends on your needs

Comment: so, is there anyways that we can automated this process through API? or we need to log into server and do it manually?